# mysqli query returning false, apparently because the connection is becoming stale

Tags: php, mysqli

I've inherited a body of PHP 7.2 code that uses the *mysqli* library to access two databases;  one of them is in an Azure instance.  The junior developer who wrote this lot reckons that the connection object becomes stale or invalid after time so he simply re-initialises it, as described below.

Initialisation is done with:

```
$conn = mysqli_init();
mysqli_real_connect($conn, $host, $user, $pw, $database, 3306);
```

the code then uses $conn->query() a lot but after about 30 seconds, the calls start returning false.  He has dealt with this by simply repeating the call to the initialisation code above.  The problem is with increasingly large data-sets and other timing issues, the decision on where to insert the (re-)initialisations is becoming risk-prone and unreliable.

This code was returning false:

```
$results = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM cdr.cdr_data WHERE cid = 126634 AND c_time >= 1562457600 AND c_time < 1565136000 ORDER BY c_time DESC");
```

Those two column names are both integers, not strings.  When I added some more (re-)initialisation calls closer to the point of failure **and made no other change**, the query succeeded and returned the expected rows from the table.

It does seem that the connection object is becoming corrupted or stale in some way but I can't find any reference to any such phaenomenon.  Once a connection has been made, it should remain valid until closed.  Or should it?

Comment: I think Azure simply kills “idle” connections after a certain time. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-connectivity explicitly lists _“An idle connection is dropped on the server side. When you try to issue a command it can't be executed”_ as one of the cases your app should be able to handle as part of “transient connectivity errors”.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen this happening with leaking resultsets; while every resultset **should** be automatically freed when trying to read past its end point, this is not necessarily true when:

- The resultset is seekable (i.e. reversible)
- The resultset is not read entirely (last called fetch doesn't return false)
- Unexplained bugs

Therefore, it is always recommendable to close `mysqli_free_result` always when you are done with reading the results of a query. Do this and I think your headache will go away.

Also unset (nullify) references to the resultsets (the results of the stmt query), make sure you are not hoarding these object references in some variables. As long as there is a reference to an object, the object doesn't get destroyed, using up memory and possibly open handles.